# Material-ui sample code not compiling

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, material-ui

I'm a novice to React and programming generally so I may be making a painfully obvious mistake here, and I apologize if that's the case. 
I'm currently building my first components in React. I'm relying heavily on sample code from Material-ui, and I successfully built two grids, but when i attempted to build a combo-box component it would not compile at all. Here is the npm-debug log I'm getting:

```
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.11.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error metadata-application@1.0.0 start: `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-
server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the metadata-application@1.0.0 start script 'node 
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the metadata-
application package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-
server.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
23 error     npm bugs metadata-application
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls metadata-application
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And here is my unedited (the sample code from Material-ui.com) component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const styles = {
 customWidth: {
  width: 200,
  },
};

export default class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 1};
   }

  handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
         </DropDownMenu>
        <br />
        <DropDownMenu
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={styles.customWidth}
          autoWidth={false}
        >
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Custom width" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
         </DropDownMenu>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Here is my index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DropDownMenuSimpleExample from './components/test_combo';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenuSimpleExample />
      </div>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

I've checked for syntax errors and maybe I'm missing one but I can't find any. I think this whole problem is probably due to my inexperience, so I'm incredibly grateful to anyone that spends time helping me out. I have got the React plugin for atom and it hasn't thrown up any syntax errors.

Comment: Just tell us what is the error shown in the terminal (Some red lines displayed in the terminal as an error) instead of giving whole npm-debug log.

Comment: Here is the error i'm getting in the terminal:

> node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any problem in syntax.

As the node-debug log says,

> 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed.

Update the npm first using following command.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Then try deleting node_modules folder and run `npm install` again in project's root folder. Hope you installed material-ui package already, if not, run `npm install material-ui`.

This will definitely solve your problem. In worst case, try creating new project after updating npm package and do the above steps as usual. Because projects which is created by older version of npm may lead to these kinds of errors.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ganesh  I'll try out what you suggested and let you know how I go

Comment: @SWynter Glad it helped you. Accept the answer if it works.